# Enforcing constraints on weight matrices using ReLU activation

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

In the paper '[A Deep Non-Negative Matrix Factorization Neural Network](http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/BHunter/papers/deep-negative-matrix.pdf)' by Flunner and Hunter, proof of Theorem 1 says that "The ReLu Activation function is a standard approximation of a non-negative constraint", though no proof of such an argument is given, but I can't find such a claim anywhere, neither the experiments that I have run, shows confirmatory results. So, is the above argument in the paper true?

Comment: Not pretty sure the meaning of approximation here, but, "by construction", ReLU only outputs non-negative values; otherwise, clips the value to zero.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But if my weights have been initialized as negative, the gradient of ReLU will be zero, hence not updating the weights, so the weights will remain negative, as my given input vectors are non negative. So, the "approximation" does not per se, hold if all my weights are initialized as negative.